# Debian etch mod rewrite problem

Tags: mod-rewrite

Im using a debian etch and apache 2, with webmin.

Mod rewrite is working on my server but when ever i use this code in my .htaccess, i get 500 error.

*Options +FollowSymlinks*

*RewriteEngine On*

*RewriteBase /*

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.eu$ [NC]

*RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.eu/$1 [R=301,L]*

I also get this error in the apache error log:

**Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that etch has no security support left?

Comment: no i didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled the rewrite module?

`a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: Additionally, what is your AllowOverride set to in your apache config?

Comment: Yes it is enabled, when ever i use that command i get "module is already running"

Comment: The defualt file found in /etc/apache2/sites-available is set to ON, here is a portion of it

Comment: NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 
<Directory /var/www//>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
                # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
                # RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

After you fixed that, you also have a problem with the RewriteRule.
The asterisk can't stand at the end of the line. Probably it's missing after the dot so you don't only match single-letter page names.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.eu/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get the error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info guys after browsing about i solved the problem by adding this line to the bottom of my apache2.conf file, found /etc/apache2:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Now it works fine :)